# Docker container (redmine) not starting

Tags: docker, redmine, docker-container

I have created a redmine container using the below command.

> docker run -d --name redmine -v /var/lib/docker/volumes/DevVolume/redmine -p 3000:3000 --link MYSQL:mysql redmine

I'm trying to copy the plugins folder inside redmine container but after doing so, the container is not starting. It is going in exit mode. It is not starting even after restarting it multiple times. Tried all commands like

> docker start  `docker ps -a -q --filter "name=redmine"`
>
> docker restart container_name
>
> docker start container_name.

Can anyone help??

Comment: it is showing                                                                             CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                    COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS                          PORTS                                              NAMES
b0417bc24719        redmine                  "/docker-entrypoint.…"   29 minutes ago      Restarting (6) 39 seconds ago

Comment: Can you provide container's logs? Execute "docker logs redmine"